# PHP regex to find ? or = is not working

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write code to see if a website url has any "=" or "?" in the url

I have the url in $website (example www.smith.com?page=1) should be found but it is not in the following code

```
$cleanurl_text = "You appear to have a clean url structure.";


$regex = '/=/i';
if (preg_match($regex, $website)) 
{
   $cleanurl_text = "You do not appear to have a clean url structure.";
}
$regex = '/?/i';   
if (preg_match($regex, $website)) 
{
   $cleanurl_text = "You do not appear to have a clean url structure.";
}
```

Comment: To the downvoter, please explain why you think this deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use regex for this but more http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

anyway if you still want your regex you should do something  like this

```
$regex = '/=|\?/';   
if (preg_match($regex, $website)) 
{
    $cleanurl_text = "You do not appear to have a clean url structure.";
}
```

Comment: "If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function `strpos()` instead."

Answer (score 4):

If you're just matching a constant single character, regular expressions are not the best way. A more efficient regular expression would be `/=|\?/`, which tests for either `=` or `?`. The reason your expressions are not working is because `?` is a character which needs escaping. You can learn about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).

Comment: `=` needs no escaping, nor do they need `/i`.

Comment: @Qtax - You're right, I don't know what I was thinking. And good point about `i`, I left it in subconsciously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape these characters using backslash.

Comment: You don't need to escape `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are for PATTERNS - complicated(ish) string expression that would be otherwise tedious to express using sub-string searches. For a single character as you're doing, it is FAR more efficient to do:

```
if (strpos($website, '=') !== FALSE) {
   $cleanurl_text = "You do not appear to have a clean url structure.";
}
```

A regex has a relatively hefty startup cost, as the pattern has to be compiled, the regex state engine initialized, etc.... All just to look for a single character. Comparatively, strpos would be "free".